# Spark Cluster: initial job has not accept any resources and executor keep exit

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing, exit, executor

I have a spark cluster using cloud resource in two instances. One as master and one as worker. The total resource is 4 cores and 10G ram. 
I can start shell, and worker can register successfully. But when I run simple code.

The error from shell is:
Spark version:2.3.0
System: CentOS v7
The firewalls are stopped.

Here is the config:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144
export SPARK_MASTER_IP=IP
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=2g
export SPARK_WORK_INSTANCES=1
export SPARK_WORkER_CORES=4
export SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=1g
```

I set up another spark cluster using the similar config using three physical machines and they worked well. At the start I got the same error, but I solved it by stopping the firewalls. Right I want to set up the cluster on cloud, and unfortunately I got the same error, but didn't  resolve it using the same solution. I am curious whether it is the port problem, because I only open the port on http 80,4040,6066,7077,8080,8081,8787.

Here is the error:

[image]

Here are the logs:

Master log:

```
2018-04-12 13:09:14 INFO  Master:54 - Registering app Spark shell
2018-04-12 13:09:14 INFO  Master:54 - Registered app Spark shell with ID              app-20180412130914-0000
2018-04-12 13:09:14 INFO  Master:54 - Launching executor     app-20180412130914-0000/0 on worker worker-20180411144020-192.**.**.**-44986
2018-04-12 13:11:15 INFO  Master:54 - Removing executor app-20180412130914-0000/0 because it is EXITED
2018-04-12 13:11:15 INFO  Master:54 - Launching executor app-20180412130914-0000/1 on worker worker-20180411144020-192.**.**.**-44986
2018-04-12 13:13:16 INFO  Master:54 - Removing executor app-20180412130914-0000/1 because it is EXITED
2018-04-12 13:13:16 INFO  Master:54 - Launching executor app-20180412130914-0000/2 on worker worker-20180411144020-192.**.**.**-44986
2018-04-12 13:15:17 INFO  Master:54 - Removing executor app-20180412130914-0000/2 because it is EXITED
2018-04-12 13:15:17 INFO  Master:54 - Launching executor app-20180412130914-0000/3 on worker worker-20180411144020-192.**.**.**-44986
2018-04-12 13:16:15 INFO  Master:54 - Removing app app-20180412130914-0000
2018-04-12 13:16:15 INFO  Master:54 - 192.**.**.**:39766 got disassociated, removing it.
2018-04-12 13:16:15 INFO  Master:54 - IP:39928 got disassociated, removing it.
2018-04-12 13:16:15 WARN  Master:66 - Got status update for unknown executor app-20180412130914-0000/3
```

Worker log:

```
2018-04-12 13:09:12 INFO  Worker:54 - Asked to launch executor    app-20180412130914-0000/0 for Spark shell
2018-04-12 13:09:12 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls to: root
2018-04-12 13:09:12 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing modify acls to: root
2018-04-12 13:09:12 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls groups to: 
2018-04-12 13:09:12 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing modify acls groups  to: 
2018-04-12 13:09:12 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions:    Set(root); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(root); groups with modify permissions: Set()
2018-04-12 13:09:12 INFO  ExecutorRunner:54 - Launch command: "/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/java" "-cp" "/opt/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/:/opt/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/*" "-Xmx1024M" "-Dspark.driver.port=39928" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "--driver-url" "spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@IP:39928" "--executor-id" "0" "--hostname" "192.**.**.**" "--cores" "4" "--app-id" "app-20180412130914-0000" "--worker-url" "spark://Worker@192.**.**.**:44986"
2018-04-12 13:11:13 INFO  Worker:54 - Executor app-20180412130914-0000/0 finished with state EXITED message Command exited with code 1 exitStatus 1
2018-04-12 13:11:13 INFO  Worker:54 - Asked to launch executor app-20180412130914-0000/1 for Spark shell
2018-04-12 13:11:13 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls to: root
2018-04-12 13:11:13 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing modify acls to: root
2018-04-12 13:11:13 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls groups to: 
2018-04-12 13:11:13 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing modify acls groups to: 
2018-04-12 13:11:13 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(root); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(root); groups with modify permissions: Set()
2018-04-12 13:11:13 INFO  ExecutorRunner:54 - Launch command: "/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/java" "-cp" "/opt/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/:/opt/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/*" "-Xmx1024M" "-Dspark.driver.port=39928" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "--driver-url" "spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@spark-master.novalocal:39928" "--executor-id" "1" "--hostname" "192.**.**.**" "--cores" "4" "--app-id" "app-20180412130914-0000" "--worker-url" "spark://Worker@192.**.**.**:44986"
2018-04-12 13:13:15 INFO  Worker:54 - Executor app-20180412130914-0000/1 finished with state EXITED message Command exited with code 1 exitStatus 1
2018-04-12 13:13:15 INFO  Worker:54 - Asked to launch executor app-20180412130914-0000/2 for Spark shell
2018-04-12 13:13:15 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls to: root
2018-04-12 13:13:15 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing modify acls to: root
2018-04-12 13:13:15 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls groups to: 
2018-04-12 13:13:15 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing modify acls groups to: 
2018-04-12 13:13:15 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(root); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(root); groups with modify permissions: Set()
2018-04-12 13:13:15 INFO  ExecutorRunner:54 - Launch command: "/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/java" "-cp" "/opt/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/:/opt/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/*" "-Xmx1024M" "-Dspark.driver.port=39928" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "--driver-url" "spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@spark-master.novalocal:39928" "--executor-id" "2" "--hostname" "192.**.**.**" "--cores" "4" "--app-id" "app-20180412130914-0000" "--worker-url" "spark://Worker@192.**.**.**:44986"
2018-04-12 13:15:16 INFO  Worker:54 - Executor app-20180412130914-0000/2 finished with state EXITED message Command exited with code 1 exitStatus 1
```

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this issue? I'm getting the same thing